# How to download data from OECD by using R package

Tags: r

I am trying to download data directly from the OECD website using the OECD package in R. I'm specifically trying to download data from "Employment by activities and status (ALFS) ARCHIVE" which data set is `ALFS_EMP_ARCHIVE`
https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?QueryId=78721#

My step as follow:
Firstly,

```
library(OECD)
dataset<-"ALFS_EMP_ARCHIVE"
dstruc <- get_data_structure(dataset)
```

but report

```
  trying to get slot "concepts" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object
```

and I follow the [How to use function "get_data_structure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245454/how-to-use-function-get-data-structure)
is not work

Secondly,try this
[downloading data from OECD website using the OECD package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430397/downloading-data-from-oecd-website-using-the-oecd-package-in-r?rq=1)

```
df <- get_dataset("ALFS_EMP_ARCHIVE",
                  filter = list(c(),"AUS"),start_time = 2008, end_time = 2016)
```

report

```
rror in download.file(path, destfile, method, quiet, mode, ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/ALFS_EMP_ARCHIVE/.AUS/all?startTime=2008&endTime=2016'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(path, destfile, method, quiet, mode, ...) :
  cannot open URL 'https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/ALFS_EMP_ARCHIVE/.AUS/all?startTime=2008&endTime=2016': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'
```

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to CRAN and try the examples in the official OECD R library manual.

When a library or library documentation on CRAN is out-of-date or not working properly it gets flagged. The author then has limited time to fix it, or it gets removed from CRAN. CRAN should always be the first place you look to try to understand the functions of a library. The documentation on CRAN is usually up-to-date.

Try the examples in the manual.

[CRAN - OECD OFFICIAL R MANUAL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OECD/OECD.pdf)

```
library(OECD)
searchResults <- search_dataset('status', data = get_datasets(), ignore.case = TRUE)
ALFS_EMP <- get_dataset("ALFS_EMP_ARCHIVE", filter = list(c("AUS")),
                        start_time = 2008, end_time = 2020)
```

The search is based on a sub-string. So you don't need the complete string. Just part of the string. 'Fri' will find 'Fridge' and 'Refrigerator' because they both contain the sub-string.

The error in your code is here: `c(),"AUS")`

Comment: Thank you! I find that my dataset is wrong. It should be "ALFS_EMP". And It is OK now.